Ajuda com o código abaixo busca arquivos com numeração a partir de 6 carateres
$arquivo=fopen("../storage/app/private/codigos/files.txt", "r");
$desenhos=[];
while (($buffer = fgets($arquivo, 4096)) !== false) {
$desenhos[utf8_encode(trim(substr($buffer, 0, 6)))]=true;

Recomendo você a ler novamente as indicações que recebeu nna pergunta que excluiu anteriormente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/594245/5878

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).

Logica ta errada, primeiro você tem listar os arquivos depois buscar.
<?php
$directory = "../storage/app/private/codigos/";
$handle = opendir($directory);

if ($handle) {
    $desenhos = [];
    
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (strlen($entry) >= 6) {
            $desenhos[$entry] = true;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo "Arquivos 6 caracteres:\n";
    print_r(array_keys($desenhos));
} else {
    echo "Erro";
}


Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.
